# What's a good way of keeping the order of my model instances matched with the order of a list on my page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI's Sortable feature, and as such, the order of my list changes a lot.

The list is initially generated using a simple call like so:

```
@todos = Todo.where(done:false)
```

How do i preserve the order that the user decides on when I load the view?

Comment: can you explain with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking for, but if you want to order the list in query you can do this, here `.order` is used to fetch the records order by something, here in this example I've used `created_at DESC`.

```
@todos = Todo.where(done:false).order("created_at desc")
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not clear your question,if you want maintain order in all the query you can use default_scope in your model

Ex:

```
  class Achievement < ActiveRecord::Base
      default_scope order("created_at desc")
  end
```

in console:

```
 Achievement.where(:achievement_type => "testimonials")
 #=> Achievement Load (2.4ms)  SELECT "achievements".* FROM "achievements" WHERE "achievements"."achievement_type" = 'testimonials' **ORDER BY created_at desc**
```

order will come automatically in all query.